# Custom jquery tabs problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

please check http://jsfiddle.net/w3father/4Z7pe/

i want to show tabs content when user click (without time delay) but auto play need time delay

Comment: Could you please me more specific with you intended outcome.

Comment: First of all you should more concentrate on the basics. You're code is crashing slow browsers if you click more than three times. [jQuery animation stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) would be the first thing to admit.

Comment: Now my auto play works perfectly but we click tab that has take some time delay.So i want to differentiate user click and script fired click.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these points:

- implement a local variable for userInteraction

  - set this variable to true if the user clicks your links
  - if this variable is true your interval method should do? -> nothing!
  - stop all happening animations and minimize every tab instead of the clicked

I think those ideas should help. If you have further questions, just ask.

**Try to seperate the code a little bit more. Javascript is object-orientated aswell!**

/edit:

Let me abstract this a little bit for you:

```
var currTab;
var userInteraction;
function intervalAction() {
    if (userInteraction) return;
    else showTab(currTab++);
}

function showTab(tab) {
    // stop running animations
    // hide every tab
    // show the tab that is wanted
}
```

Use the code you've already written and place it inside. Upload it to jsfiddle again and let me see **your** results.

Comment: thanks dude.I'm not experienced with jquery but i have to do it. please can u help me more